# order custom post type posts by custom date

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, order

Trying to order posts by a custom field, where a date i stored. The date looks like this "03.10.2019".
All of the below function works properly, but the posts are sorted by post date, not custom field date...

```
// Events Archive Ordering
function leweb_get_posts( $query ) {

    // do not modify queries in backend
    if( is_admin() ) {

        return $query;

    }   

    // only modify queries for 'events' post type
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'events' ) {

        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');   
        $query->set('meta_key', 'event_date');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 

    }


    // return
    return $query;

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'leweb_get_posts');
```

Comment: SQL can't order by a date formatted like "03.10.2019". You would need to save your custom field as a SQL timestamp in order to be able to order queries by that field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input, i solved the problem with the following workaround.

```
strtotime($event_date)
```